# Table in HTML using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I am not familiar with JavaScript and HTML. Just want to build a Table with JavaScript in HTML. I am following some instructions, part of code is as bellow. would you please let me know what is the problem that the table is not appearing?

```js
    tb1= document.createElement('table');
    var tr = tb1.insertRow();
    var Cell1 = tr.insertCell(0),
    var Cell2 = tr.insertCell(1),
    var Cell3 = tr.insertCell(2),
    var Cell4 = tr.insertCell(3);
    cell1.innerHTML = "11";
    cell2.innerHTML = "11";
    cell3.innerHTML = "11";
    cell4.innerHTML = "11";
    tb1.appendChild(MyTable);
```

```html
    <table id="MyTable" width="100%" ></table>
```

Comment: Java is not javascript. Please change the title and content so people arent confused.

Comment: Maybe you should open your browser's console and see the errors you're getting.

Comment: A couple of quick suggestions: `Cell1` and `cell1` are different things. And so are `;` and `,`.

Comment: There is more wrong with this than right. Throw this all away, read the duplicate, start again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't have to use `document.createElement('table');` if the element is in your html, use `getElementById("MyTable")`;
2. You are using commas instead of semicolon in the end of lines;

There is an example that could make you understand better:

```js
window.onload = function() {
   var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   var row = table.insertRow(0);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell1.innerHTML = "1";
    
   var row = table.insertRow(1);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell1.innerHTML = "1";
    
   var row = table.insertRow(2);
   var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
   cell1.innerHTML = "1";
};
```

```css
table, td {
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

```html
 <table id="myTable"> </table>
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
var div= document.getElementById('MyTableContainer');
var tb1= document.createElement('table');
var tr = tb1.insertRow();
var cell1 = tr.insertCell(0);
var cell2 = tr.insertCell(1);
var cell3 = tr.insertCell(2);
var cell4 = tr.insertCell(3);
cell1.innerHTML = "11";
cell2.innerHTML = "11";
cell3.innerHTML = "11";
cell4.innerHTML = "11";
div.appendChild(tb1);
```

```css
#MyTable > table {
  width: 100%;
}

td {
border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="MyTableContainer" width="100%" ></div>
```

Comment: This *could* be a good answer but you need to do more than just vomit some code into it. As it stands it's just a poor answer to a poor question